# How to Name a RESTLER json Result

Tags: php, json, restler

Forgive my terminology im a newbie in in web dev.

To visualize my question, see below.

This is how RESTLER displays json:

> ```
> [
>  {
>    "id": 1,
>    "name": "Daniel Craig",
>    "email": "dc@gmail.com"
>  },
>  {
>    "id": 2,
>    "name": "Tom Cruise",
>    "email": "tc@gmail.com"
>  }
> ]
> ```

This is how i would want RESTLER to display json results:

> ```
> {"actors":[
>  {
>    "id": 1,
>    "name": "Daniel Craig",
>    "email": "dc@gmail.com"
>  },
>  {
>    "id": 2,
>    "name": "Tom Cruise",
>    "email": "tc@gmail.com"
>  }
> ]}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your result with another array. if we assume that `$result` returns the first result above, do the following

```
$result = array(
 array(
   "id" => 1,
   "name" => "Daniel Craig",
   "email" => "dc@gmail.com"
 ),
 array(
   "id" => 2,
   "name" => "Tom Cruise",
   "email" => "tc@gmail.com"
 )
);

return array('actors'=>$result);
```